# 2048 AI in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ai, 2048

I am working on an 2048 AI and this is my code so far.

In the game 2048 you have a 4x4 grid in that some random so named tiles spawn.
Each tile has a number. The lowest number is 2.
By using the left, right, up and down-key you can move all tiles into the specified direction. If two tiles with the same number "collide" they merge into one and sum up there numbers.

Example:

```
 ___ ___ ___ ___
|___|___|___|_2_|
|___|___|_2_|___|
|___|___|___|_2_|
|___|___|___|___|

DOWN
 ___ ___ ___ ___
|___|___|___|___|
|___|___|___|___|
|___|___|___|___|
|___|___|_2_|_4_|
```

You can get all needed files on [Github](https://github.com/codeglow/2048-AI/tree/ff1050a9ae5523edaa1491104de119e685cfc76b). My AI uses the Minimax-algorithm to calculate the best move.

I've tested it [here](https://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/) and got scores around 10,000 Points with getting the 1024-tile.

```
import pyautogui
import collections
import operator
import math
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
import random

game  = [0] * 16

UP    = 0
DOWN  = 1
LEFT  = 2
RIGHT = 3

step  = 6

def printGame(game=game):
    print('')
    for i in range(3):
        print(end=' ')
        for j in range(3):
            print(str(game[i * 4 + j] if game[i * 4 + j] else '').center(4), '| ', end='')
        print(str(game[i * 4 + 3] if game[i * 4 + 3] else '').center(4))
        print('------|------|------|------')
    print(end=' ')
    for j in range(3):
        print(str(game[12 + j] if game[12 + j] else '').center(4), '| ', end='')
    print(str(game[12 + 3] if game[12 + 3] else '').center(4))
    print('')

def getTiles():
    tiles = {}
    screen = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(pyautogui.screenshot()), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    for tileNumber in [0, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024]:
        template = cv2.imread('tile' + str(tileNumber) + '.png', 0)
        w, h = template.shape[::-1]
        res = cv2.matchTemplate(screen, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        locations = np.where(res >= .8)
        for location in zip(*locations[::-1]):
            location = pyautogui.center((location[0], location[1], w, h))
            tiles[round(location[0] / 100), round(location[1] / 100)] = tileNumber
    od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(tiles.items()))
    i = 0
    for k, v in od.items():
        game[i % 4 * 4 + math.floor(i / 4)] = v
        i += 1

def ij(direction, i, j, offset=0):
    if direction == UP:
        return (3 - j - offset) * 4 + i
    elif direction == DOWN:
        return (j + offset) * 4 + i
    elif direction == LEFT:
        return i * 4 + 3 - j - offset
    elif direction == RIGHT:
        return i * 4 + j + offset

def move(game, direction, step=step):
    tmpgame = game.copy()
    for i in range(4):
        lj = -1
        for j in range(4):
            if game[ij(direction, i, j)] != 0:
                if lj > -1 and game[ij(direction, i, j)] == game[lj]:
                    game[lj] = 0
                    game[ij(direction, i, j)] *= 2
                    lj = -1
                else:
                    lj = ij(direction, i, j)
    for i in range(4):
        l = []
        for j in range(4):
            l.append(game[ij(direction, 3 - i, 3 - j)])
        l = [x for x in l if x != 0]
        while len(l) < 4:
            l.append(0)
        for j in range(4):
            game[ij(direction, 3 - i, 3 - j)] = l[j]
    if tmpgame == game:
        return 0
    elif step > 0:
        return multispawn(game, step)
    else:
        return sum(game) * game.count(0)

def multimove(game, step):
    l = []
    for i in range(4):
        l.append(move(game.copy(), i, step))
    return max(l)

def spawn(game, tile, i, j, step=step):
    game[i * 4 + j] = 2
    if step > 0:
        return multimove(game, step - 1)
    else:
        return sum(game) * game.count(0)

def multispawn(game, step):
    l = []
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            if game[i * 4 + j] == 0:
                l.append(spawn(game.copy(), 2, i, j, step - 1))
                l.append(spawn(game.copy(), 4, i, j, step - 1))
                if 0 in l:
                    return 0
    if len(l) == 0:
        if step > 0:
            return multimove(game, step - 1)
        else:
            return sum(game) * game.count(0)
    else:
        return min(l)

def main():
    time.sleep(2)
    while True:
        getTiles()
        printGame()

        count = {}

        count['up'] = move(game.copy(), UP)
        print('up', count['up'])

        count['down'] = move(game.copy(), DOWN)
        print('down', count['down'])

        count['left'] = move(game.copy(), LEFT)
        print('left', count['left'])

        count['right'] = move(game.copy(), RIGHT)
        print('right', count['right'])

        count = [x for x,y in count.items() if y == max(count.values())]

        pyautogui.press(count[random.randint(0, len(count) - 1)])

        time.sleep(0.2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```